# pinging a role in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix=",")

  @client.command()
  @commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
  async def trade(ctx):
    role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'punishment')
```

When I run this I get error saying "get" is not defined which makes sense but i tried many other ways like "discord.get" and "client.roles.get"
But none worked
please tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: Can you give more context to your question please ? What is this `get` function you're trying to use ? I don't see how this code is related to pinging. We miss informations here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `discord.utils.get` (I assume)

so to call it you must write

```py
import discord

...

role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'punishment')
```

instead of

```py
import discord

...

role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'punishment')
```

Or alternatively import it like this

```py
from discord.utils import get

...

role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name = 'punishment')
```